# Download an image hosted in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have a URL like this who corresponds to an image shown in a website:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/welook-siwe.appspot.com/o/moments%2F58810%2Ffe2c6769-af55-4fb3-a73f-4bac3bb2dbc3?alt=media&token=a123aaa3-7e77-4f1a-88cb-9f5169fd5b6e

I need to download that image but i can't because it just downloads me this kind of file when i click on the URL: [image]

Is there any way to download that image using only the URL?

Comment: Can you explain "download that image using only the URL" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Changing the file name while saving

If you want to download the `image manually`, Just download it, and save it as `you_filename.jpg`. When you add the extension, your file explorer is smart enough to decode the image, and you can see the thumbnail.

## Using Python Requests

As the weblink have the media access token, you can download the image using simple `get` request. Make sure you write the file name with the file extension `donwloadedimage.jpg` as given below

```py
import requests

def download_image(url):
    r = requests.get(url=url)
    path="downloadedimage.jpg"

    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("File Downloaded")
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
            print("File Saved")
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")

download_url="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/welook-siwe.appspot.com/o/moments%2F58810%2Ffe2c6769-af55-4fb3-a73f-4bac3bb2dbc3?alt=media&token=a123aaa3-7e77-4f1a-88cb-9f5169fd5b6e"
download_image(download_url)
```

#### While Uploading

Make sure you upload the image with the `extension`. If you upload without extension , Firebase will consider the `object-type` as not as `image/jpg` but as `application/octet-stream`

#### When File Extension is not provided in Firebase

[image]

If you did that, reupload the image with right extension by renaming the file with right extension `(jpg/jpeg/png)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Content-Disposition: attachment` to the header of a file when uploading it to storage. This will tell the browser to download, not display the image in a browser.

**Example Firebase v9:**

```js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'

async function onChangeFileUpload(file) {
    const imageRef = ref(getStorage(), `images/${file.value.files[0].name}`)
    const metadata = {
        contentDisposition: 'attachment'
    }
    const result = await uploadBytes(imageRef, file.value.files[0], metadata)
    const doUrl = await getDownloadURL(result.ref)
    // Save downloadURL link in database.
}
```

Another way, if you want user to download any file by one click, you need to use `<a href="" download>`.

**Downloading file via link:**

```js
<a href="https://example.com/link/to/your/file.jpg" download>Download File>></a>
```

By the way, your link is lack of file extension `.jpg`.